# C# Null coalesce with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, null-coalescing

I have 2 classes which looks like this:

```
class Widget
{
    string Selected { get; set; }

    List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

class Option
{
    string InternalCode { get; set; }

    string ExternalCode { get; set; }
}
```

`Options` gets populated dynamically with different data per client for showing `ExternalCode` as options

`Selected` gets populated with `ExternalCode`.

I then need to access the `InternalCode` which matches.

At present I am doing this:

```
var option = widget.Options.SingleOrDefault(o => o.ExternalCode == widget.Selected);

var internalCode = option == null ? string.Empty : option.InternalCode;
```

Is this possible using a single line using Null Coalesce?

Comment: Why the null check on option? it's never null or a possible NullReferenceException

Comment: @Sievajet It can be null if no matching option is found - SingleOrDefault will return default(T) in that scenario, which will be null for this case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can use the null propagation and null coalescing operator, which suits your needs if you can use C# 6:

```
var option = widget.Options
             .SingleOrDefault(o => o.ExternalCode == widget.Selected)?.InternalCode
             ?? string.Empty;
```

The `?.` will translate to your use of the `option == null ?` part.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I couldn't figure out  where to access the property. The `?.Property` is what I was missing.

Comment: The code showed so far does not work in cases where there is a matching instance of `Option` with `InternalCode == null`

Answer (score 9):

Sure, with a small change:

```
var option = widget.Options
                   .Where(o => o.ExternalCode == widget.Selected)
                   .Select(o => o.InternalCode)
                   .FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
```

In other words, project the sequence of matching options to a sequence of internal codes, and then take the first of *those*, defaulting to `null`... which allows you to use the null-coalescing operator on the result.

You can use the null-conditional operator as per Patrick's answer instead, but personally I'd prefer the code in this answer - I think it's simpler to understand.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using `Select` instead of the null propagation operator? (besides the need of C# 6 for my answer?)

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Only that I think it's simpler to understand this, IMO. Definitely a personal opinion though.

Comment: Yes, indeed. You can easily miss the `?`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you wrote extension method:

```
public static class MonadExtensions
{
    public static TResult With<TSource, TResult>(TSource source, Func<TSource, TResult> action) where TSource : class
        {
            if (source != default(TSource))
                return action(source);
            return default(TResult);
        }
}
```

And use it:

```
var internalCode  = widget.Options.SingleOrDefault(o => o.ExternalCode == widget.Selected).With(o=>o.InternalCode)??"";
```

Comment: A good answer however it doesn't use null coalesce and it isn't 1 line!

Comment: you can use monads nugget package to not write this extension method: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Monads/ and, of cause, it uses nullcoalesce operator ??

Comment: I'll check out Monads

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible using a single line using Null Coalesce?

Yes, here is how:

```cs
var option = (widget.Options.SingleOrDefault(o => o.ExternalCode == widget.Selected) ?? new Option() { InternalCode = string.Empty }).InternalCode;
```

The other answers using a single statement I have seen so far yield wrong results in cases where there is a matching instance of `Option` with `InternalCode == null`