# In a timeseries of column values - how can i use previous available value if row value is null. c# (Datatable/Datarow)

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I'm reading Datatable column values into an array but my current code **skips null values.**

**Question -**

How can I achieve the following within the code listed below -

*If null value then read the previous available value in the time series.*

**For example - note these are column values.... **

**Input - 8,9,10,'','',5,11,3,'',2**

**Code output  - 8,9,10,5,11,3,2**

***Expect_Result* - 8,9,10,10,10,5,11,3,3,2**

Code -

```
public static double[] DataTableColumn(DataTable table, string "dbColumn")
    {
        var column = new List<string>();
        foreach (
           string columnsize in
           from DataRow resultRow in table.Rows
           select resultRow[columnName].ToString().Split('|') into sizes
           from size in sizes
           where !column.Contains(size)
           select size)
        {
            column.Add(columnsize);
        }

        string[] columnarray = column.ToArray();
        double[] doublearray = Array.ConvertAll(columnarray, Double.Parse);

        return doublearray;
    }
```

FYI - *DataTableColumn* input *DataTable table* is from the below code

```
 public static DataTable DataSet()
    {
        string sql = string.Format(@"select * from dbtable);

        System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            connection.Open();

            OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

            command.CommandText = sql;
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


            table.TableName = "Table";
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(table);
            Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
            Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString: {0}",
                              connection.ConnectionString);
        }         

        return table;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some example input for DataTableColumn? I'm currently just trying to understand what the LINQ is doing (alternative to supplying input you can just explain it).

Comment: Can you simply check if the current columnsize is null and add the previous columnsize (or am I missing something)?

Comment: @BlakeThingstad - i have added the example input for DataTableColumn. Think of input values as what I have listed in the example 
Data_table_column - 8,9,10,'','',5,11,3,'',2

Comment: @user365213 - That is exactly my question.. how can i check within the select statement if columnsize is null then use previous value?

Comment: What does "How to roll previous row value" mean exactly? rephrase the title perhaps.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss i have rephrased the title.. please see the example values of input and expected output in bold.

Comment: `string sql = string.Format(@"select * from dbtable);` is not valid syntax...perhaps you just mean to use `string sql = @"select * from dbtable";` here?

Comment: This feels like what you might want was a null coalescing operator in your linq as here https://stackoverflow.com/q/34630920/125981

Answer (score 1):

The below code produces your desired output with your supplied input.

What I have changed about your code is that when the value is empty, it recursively finds the previous value that is not empty.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("column1"));
    var values = new string[] { "8", "9|10", "", "", "5", "11", "3", "", "2" };
    foreach (var value in values)
        dt.Rows.Add(value);
    var result = DataTableColumn(dt, "column1");
    // result contains 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 5, 11, 3, 3, 2
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

public static double[] DataTableColumn(DataTable table, string columnName)
{
    var split = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .SelectMany(r => r[columnName].ToString().Split('|'))
        .ToList();
    var replaceEmpty = split.Select((v, i) => 
           string.IsNullOrEmpty(v) ? Previous(split, i) : v)
        .ToArray();
    return Array.ConvertAll(replaceEmpty, Double.Parse);
}

public static string Previous(List<string> list, int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

    var prev = list[index - 1];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prev))
        return Previous(list, index - 1);
    else
        return prev;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude... 

this gave me a good idea. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the only change to make is 
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[index]))
        return Previous(list, index - 1);
    else
        return list[index];


Thanks again

Comment: i have posted the revised code to solve this problem.

Comment: @war10ck Glad to help =)

Answer (score 0):

if you know which columns could be null then its simple you can write something similar to this in sql

```
Data_table_column - 8,9,10,'','',5,11,3,'',2
select col1, col2, col3, 
 ISNULL(col4,col3)col4,ISNULL(col5,col3)col5, col6, col7, col8,
 ISNULL(col9,col8) col9, col10 from #tttt
```

or you can update your array in your code to check if an element is null/empty then set the value from `array[arrayIndex] = array[arrayIndex-1]`

Hope this will give you some ideas

Comment: 1. to clarify its not the column names - ... the code is reading column values from the sql and storing in an array. while reading the column values it skips null values.

2. the code doesn't reach the array part..

by the time code stores the column values in the array - it contains filtered null values..so something needs to be done when its doing a select statement.

I have added more comments for this question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you saying you do not have access to SQL query which you can amend as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static double[] GetColumnTimeSeriesFromDataTable(DataTable table, string columnName)
    {
        var split = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            .SelectMany(r => r[columnName].ToString().Split('|'))
            .ToList();
        var replaceEmpty = split.Select((v, i) =>
               string.IsNullOrEmpty(v) ? Previous(split, i) : v)
            .ToArray();
        return Array.ConvertAll(replaceEmpty, Double.Parse);
    }

    public static string Previous(List<string> list, int index)
    {
        var prev = list[index];
        if (index == 0 & string.IsNullOrEmpty(list[index])) 
            return Previous(list, index+1);
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prev))
            return Previous(list, index - 1);
        else
            return prev;
    }
```